# Calling an external api request every hour for a loggedIn user in node js

Tags: node.js

when a user logins I want to call an external api(linkedIn api) every hour for the next 10 hours. How will I achieve this in node js? Every logged In user has different hours access e.g if the loggedIn user has (1 to 5) hours  then the linkedIn api will be called every hour for the next 5 hours.

Comment: You can use setInterval with a counter and expire it when it reaches the 5th hour.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built in `setInterval()` function to execute code at a given rate (in milliseconds)

```js
setInterval(() => {
    // Your code here
}, 3600000) // one hour is 3,600,000 milliseconds
```